# What does the constructor do in the @HiltViewModel

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am attempting to add Hilt DI to a view model class.

1. It's not clear to be from the docs (in layman's terms) what the constructor is used for?
2. All the Google docs also indicate you need to add this : ViewModel interface after the constructor but I am also curious what purpose that interface serves?

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(

) : ViewModel() {
    private val _myVal: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf("")
    val myVal get() = _myVal.value

    fun setMyVal (myVal: String) {
        _myVal.value = phoneNumber
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you're not injecting in anything in your constructor (which would be the whole point of using `@HiltViewModel` and `@Inject` in the first place), so it isn't doing anything at all for you at the moment. Did you already read the [ViewModel Overview guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)?

Comment: Yeah, the ViewModel makes sense, and also with State Hoisting.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mymWGMy9pYI&t=321s

But now I want two Composables to share the same View Model.  I am not connecting the dots.

Comment: I'm not sure what Hilt DI has do with sharing a ViewModel across two different composable screens? You can do that with or without Hilt.

Comment: I don't know what it has to do with it either.  A $200 an hour consultant told me I needed it but could not explain it.

Comment: If your actual problem is 'you want to share a ViewModel across two different composable screens, and tried to do X, but that didn't work', then maybe you should ask _that_ question - it sounds like you've just falling into an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) kind of situation. You can link it here if you'd like me to take a look at it.